# In which branch of engineering can I learn about display technologies like LCD, LED, OLED?

Tags: display, dot-matrix-display

I am finishing high school this year and want to pursue a career where I can learn and develop display technologies like LCD, LED, OLED, and flexible displays.

Can somebody please tell me what branch of engineering I should opt for?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is only about specific issues in the *practice* of engineering, and not about engineering career or educational paths.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Do you know if there is a SE that would fit this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. practically speaking your first step will be a bachelors degree. Go for mechanical or electrical engineering. Both are involved when developing displays. I'd say go for whichever aspect seems most interesting to you.